# JerseyClient returns 401 on JIRA API, although curl works

Tags: curl, jersey, basic-authentication, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to access JIRA through their API.

Unfortunatly I receive a 401, when trying to access them through the jersey-client (version 2.30.1)

`Authentication error (401) for user user@my-company.com`

Here comes my code:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.authentication.HttpAuthenticationFeature
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType

....

    val clientConfig = ClientConfig()

    val feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("user@my-company.com", "myS3cr3tApiToken")
    clientConfig.register(feature)

    val client: Client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig)
    val webTarget: WebTarget = client.target("https://my-company.atlassian.net").path("/rest/api/latest/search")

    val invocationBuilder: Invocation.Builder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    val response = invocationBuilder.get()
```

If I run the same with curl, everything works fine:

`curl --user user@my-company.com:myS3cr3tApiToken https://my-company.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/search`

What can be the cause for that?

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced that using the non-Preemptive works for me.
So I just used the following feature instead of the above one:

```
val feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basicBuilder()
        .nonPreemptive()
        .credentials("user@my-company.com", "myS3cr3tApiToken")
        .build()
    clientConfig.register(feature)
```